# Shell equivalency of os.environ in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

Does

```
os.environ["MYVAR"] = 'hello'
```

export to all child processes or just the current process? In other words, which of the following is that equivalent to?

```
export MYVAR=hello
```

or

```
MYVAR=hello
```

Comment: What has your experimenting shown?

Comment: According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) on `os.environ`, `If the platform supports the putenv() function, this mapping may be used to modify the environment as well as query the environment. putenv() will be called automatically when the mapping is modified.` Does that answer your question?

Comment: You could find out by spawning a child process.

Comment: However, do note that Popen and friends can be passed a custom env mapping (it's a keyword arg),  i.e. just because python spawned a subprocess doesn't mean it *has to* inherit the parent env.

Answer (score 0):

The environment is a process-related concept. When any program, no matter whether it is a shell script, python script, C program, etc, performs a fork, the environment is copied.
Since `os.environ` modifies the environment of the parent process when a variable is assigned, yes, child processes created with fork() after that receive the changed environment. This is equivalent to the `export NAME=VALUE` in a shell.

Comment: Hence, it is subtly wrong to identify shell variables with environment entries, though doing so is pervasive.  (Some) shell variables are initialized from the environment, but they are not themselves environment entries.  Modifications to those that are exported are synced with the environment.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I have augmented my answer to express this more clearly.